# jsPDF - Object doesn't support property or method 'table'

Tags: internet-explorer, jspdf

Hi I am trying to export a JSP page having bootstrap CSS classes to PDF.I am getting the error : Object doesn't support property or method 'table', at the line

```
renderer.pdf.table(renderer.x, renderer.y, table2json.rows, table2json.headers, {
```

in jspdf.plugin.from_html.js. I am trying in IE 10 and 11.

I have included jspdf.plugin.from_html.js, jspdf.js, split_text_to_size.js, standard_fonts_metrics.js,html2canvas.js,bluebird.min.js in my JSP apart from jquery, bootstrap classes etc.

```
<link href="../bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<script src="../jscripts/jsPDF-master/jsPDF-master/src/jspdf.js"> </script>
<script src="../jscripts/jsPDF-master/jsPDF-master/jspdf.plugin.from_html.js"> </script>
<script src="../jscripts/jsPDF-master/jsPDF-master/src/modules/split_text_to_size.js"> </script>
<script src="../jscripts/jsPDF-master/jsPDF-master/src/modules/standard_fonts_metrics.js"> </script>
<script src="../jscripts/html2canvas.js"> </script>
<script src="../jscripts/bluebird.min.js"> </script>
<script>
function demoFromHTML() {
        /*var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
  //pdf.canvas.height = 72 * 11;
  //pdf.canvas.width = 72 * 8.5;

  pdf.fromHTML(document.body);

  pdf.save('test.pdf');*/
        var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
        // source can be HTML-formatted string, or a reference
        // to an actual DOM element from which the text will be scraped.
        source = $('body')[0];

        // we support special element handlers. Register them with jQuery-style 
        // ID selector for either ID or node name. ("#iAmID", "div", "span" etc.)
        // There is no support for any other type of selectors 
        // (class, of compound) at this time.
        specialElementHandlers = {
            // element with id of "bypass" - jQuery style selector
            '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
                // true = "handled elsewhere, bypass text extraction"
                return true
            }
        };
        margins = {
            top: 80,
            bottom: 60,
            left: 40,
            width: 522
        };
        // all coords and widths are in jsPDF instance's declared units
        // 'inches' in this case
        pdf.fromHTML(
            source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
            margins.left, // x coord
            margins.top, { // y coord
                'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
                'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
            },

            function (dispose) {
                // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF 
                //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
                pdf.save('Test.pdf');
            }, margins
        );
    }
</script>
```

EDIT : I tried as suggested by @Deepak-MSFT and thankfully it is generating the PDF now(in IE 11 it works fine, not working in Chrome, but anyway I need it to work only in IE). However now there is an issue with table rendering.My page has a lot of text and a few tables too, and the tables look huge and table text overlaps. I tried with jsPDF+html2canvas to preserve the CSS styling, but its not working (though the console shows 'finished rendering', there is no PDF). As a workaround, I replaced tables with html list and now my PDF text size etc is okay but shows an error :

> An error exists on this page. Acrobat may not display the page correctly. >Please contact the person who created the PDF document to correct the problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please confirm whether your code is working with any other browser or not? It can be possible that you have some issue with your references. Please check whether any polyfil is missing.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I had tried in Chrome, there also it was not working, at the same line. the error is Uncaught TypeError: renderer.pdf.table is not a function. Also, can you please tell me what polyfils I am supposed to use? The ones already there are shown in my code above.

Comment: I suggest you to make a test with this example. Ref: https://codepen.io/mckeddmat/pen/xOPdPV you can try to modify it further.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I have tried all the html2canvas +jsPDF links out there but none of them are working in IE11... every time I get Finished Rendering in the console but there's no PDF file ... using jsPDF alone makes a mess of the tables in the PDF... What could I be missing

Comment: Are you trying to displaying the PDF in IE browser? IE will not display that. Try to download the generated PDF file for IE browser.